# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (React.js)

Tags: reactjs

I don't understand, why I have a this error:
`Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. (Line 15)

This is my file: index.js
So how Can I resolve this problem? please help. I've been struggling with this problem for several days.

```
   import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
    import {
      Grid, Paper, Typography, List
    } from '@material-ui/core/';
    import { ListItem, ListItemText } from '@material-ui/core/List';

    const styles = {
      Paper: { padding: 20, marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 10 }
    };

    export default ({ exercises }) => (
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item sm>
          <Paper style={styles.Paper}>
            {exercises.map(([group, exercises]) => (
              <Fragment>
                <Typography variant="headline" style={{ textTransform: 'capitalize' }}>
                  {group}
                </Typography>
                <List component="ul">
                  {exercises.map(({ title }) => (
                    <ListItem button>
                      <ListItemText primary={title} />
                    </ListItem>
                  ))}
                </List>
              </Fragment>
            ))}
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm>
          <Typography variant="display1">Hello</Typography>
          <Typography variant="subheading" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
            Please select an exercise from the list on the left.
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
```

Comment: Could you show us when you are using this component ?

Comment: You use exercises.map inside of exercises.map. I don't know what your error is but I would recommend cleaning up your code a little bit. 
Also what is the prop, exercises, that you passed in? 
Your problem could be you aren't passing it an array?